# Issues with France visas website to fill out online application of Schengen visa

Tags: schengen, france, applications, change-purpose-of-travel

I will be attending an academic conference in France and have been advised by the people who already have been to one of the Schengen member countries to mention the purpose of my visit as "Other" and write academic conference or colloquium.

The problem is that since December, France is taking applications from the site "French-visas" where we have to fill in an interactive online form and a PDF is generated from it. In the purpose of visit section, there is no option to mark "other" from the drop-down menu but it is showing as an available option in the generated PDF. I have tried other browsers as well, to see if there is any browser compatibility issue, but it didn't help. Any suggestions to tackle the problem?

[image]

Comment: Academic conference? Try with Study (if you are student, not paid) and in the note field add that it is a conference. Most commonly it is  business (in particular if you are a paid PhD) and mark down that it is a conference. It does not matter much the reason (but for the paper to attach), and the same people will check all kind of visa. Just make sure to note the question you are not sure (or you cannot fill 100% right). Conference and Business are similar: you go to meet people, but you are paid from home.

Comment: Yes, I am a paid PhD, but we don't have to file income tax returns since we get a scholarship and not a salary. So, if I mark business, I might be required to show salary slips, tax returns etc, which being a student I cannot produce. That is why I wanted to check "other" as a safer option. But it is not available in drop-down menu, as mentioned in original question.

Comment: Just attach a note of what you wrote here. Do you think many business traveler have such documentations? (think about founder of new companies, photographers, initial trainees on main site (e.g. in France), etc. Just your documentation will be checked more in details, but it is ok (also if you choose "Other").